# How to handle message error in Entity when using @MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jpa, mockito

I using @MockMvc test in spring controller but i have a question. 
How to handle message error when MockMvc test not pass method.

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@ApiModel(description = "All details about the Product")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid",strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;
@NotNull(message = "name can not null")
@ApiModelProperty(notes = "The name is product")
private String name;
@ApiModelProperty(notes = "The type is product")
private String type;
@NotNull(message = "category can not null")
private String category;
private String description;
private Double prince;

public Product() {
}

public Product(String name, String type, String category, String description, Double prince) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.category = category;
    this.description = description;
    this.prince = prince;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Double getPrince() {
    return prince;
}

public void setPrince(Double prince) {
    this.prince = prince;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", category='" + category + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", prince=" + prince +
            '}';


   }
}
```

**StudentController:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ProductDto> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(product.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(productService.createProduct(product));
    }
}
```

In above entity, I want using @MockMvc test createProduct. If name in product is null, i want show message in @MockMvc . It look like: "name can not null" . If pass, i don't want show it. Bellow my test:

```
@Test
public void givenProductURIWithPost_whenMockMVC_thenVerifyResponse() {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/products")).andDo(print())
      .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content()
      .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
}
```

I have two question:

```
1.How to show message "name can not null" if name in product is
null in @mockmvc.
2. If my project in 20 field in Products entity : Example: name,category.. I can test sequence field in Products or only test
one time contain all field.
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. If I understand correctly, you're asking how to validate the product before saving it. Use bean validation. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody.

Comment: `@RequestBody @Valid Product product`